# Startpage Autocomplete API

Tags: autocomplete, start-page

I' m searching for an autocomplete API for the Startpage search engine.

For Google I found:[text](http://suggestqueries.google.co/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&q=s%), but I could not find anything for Startpage.

I am looking for this API to integrate Startpage search suggestions into Firefox for Android.

I have already tried [text](http://www.startpage.com/complete/sp/q=%s) which does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

https://support.startpage.com/hc/en-us/articles/19879437555220-Startpage-Suggestions-URL

Works for me.

> Startpage Suggestions URL
>
> ```
> 1 month ago Updated
> ```
>
> Some browsers support adding suggestions URLs, allowing you to see
> Startpage (or other) search suggestions in the URL bar. If you are
> running Firefox on Android or Vivaldi on desktop, you can add
> Startpage search suggestions with the following URL:
>
> **https://www.startpage.com/osuggestions?q=%s**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
http://www.startpage.com/complete/sp/q=%s
```

use

```
https://www.startpage.com/osuggestions?q=%s
```

This works in Vivaldi for search suggestions (Jan 2024).

[Vivaldi search suggestions with Startpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S0zI.png)